# Why the fiddle is not working and there is a time lag behind in following case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, timer

My fiddle link is as follows:http://jsfiddle.net/FvYyS/2/

The function call is as follows:

```
 load_timer('0', '6', '9', 0, '0', '', '0');
```

Actually my issue is the fiddle is not working. The expected behaviour of this code is the timer should decrease second by second and ultimately reaches to zero(i.e. for example the timer should start at 00:06:09 and end at 00:00:00). But it's not working here in the fiddle. The code is working properly in my application but don't know why this code is not working in fiddle. Also one more issue I noticed in my application is the timer is lagging sometime behind. Can anyone please help me in this regard? If you need any further information I'll provide you the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has the following structure :

```
 var counter = delay;
 function loop() {
     counter--;
     displayTime(delay, counter);
     if (counter > 0) {
         setTimeout( loop, 1000 );
     }
 }
```

2 things :

- `displayTime()` execution takes time : for example, if it takes 0.2 seconds to complete, the loop will be executed every 1.2 seconds (instead of every second)
- `setTimeout( ..., 1000 )` means "Please dear javascript runtime, can you run my code in 1 second ? If you have other stuff to do, it is ok for me to wait more."
  You have the guarantee that there will be *at least* 1 second between the `setTimeout` call and your `loop` excution, but the delay can be longer.

If you want to avoid the time drift, check for the *real* time on each iteration :

```
var start = Date.now();
function loop() {
    var now = Date.now();
    var elapsedTime = now - start; //elapsed time in milliseconds
    displayTime(delay, elapsedTime);
    if (elapsedTime < delay) {
        setTimeout(loop, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you make this modification to my fiddle link?

Answer (score 1):

you have not included the `jquery library` in your fiddle

See **[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FvYyS/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your approach:

Since you do the `setTimeout` after doing some work, the time it takes for your work to be done will delay the next iterations. You could fix this by moving the `setTimeout` call to be the first executed and then do the work.

Using `setTimeout(f, timeout)` guarantees that the `f` function will be executed **at least** `timeout` miliseconds after the `setTimeout` call. So if for example the browser is busy for 1 second when the call to f should be executed, the call to f is delayed by 1 second. Furthermore, the next call to setTimeout is delayed by that second, so everything coming after that will incur your delay.

A better fix would be to use `setInterval` which is designed with repeating a task every n miliseconds and alleviates the recurrent delay problem.

Finally, the best solution to the problem is to use `Date` to determine the start of your counter and show the exact time elapsed by substracting the original time from the current time.